# Ruby on rails new app is not creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, macos-high-sierra

I started to develop the new RoR web app and faced weird issue.
I wanted to create new app with Postgresql. So I installed the Postgres with brew and MacOS desktop app. And type `rails new test-app --database=postgresql`.

```
At this moment, I can't install bundles because there is certain 
error.

An error occurred while installing pg (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot 
continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.0.0' --source 
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
   pg
          run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Could not find gem 'pg (< 2.0, >= 0.18)' in any of the gem sources 
listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So I can't start new app.
Is this an issue that is occurring because of the mismatch between ruby and postgres version?
And how can I create new app with postgres?

I am currently using Mac OS high Sierra, postgres 10.5, rails 5.2.1

Comment: Open up the project in your text editor and post your gemfile + database.yml. Also make sure to run: brew services start postgresql, or brew services list to see if its listed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to skip running Bundler: `rails new test-app --database=postgresql --skip-bundle`

Once you've generated your app, you'll still have to troubleshoot why `pg` ins't installing.  The PG gem should install just fine as long as the database is there and your system can build the gem's native extensions, so my first guess is either Postgres isn't installed or it can't be found in your environment.

Either way, this does answer your question.  Skip the bundle and voila - Rails will generate a new clean app for you.

Comment: Postgres was installed already, so I can see its version by postgres --version.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted some comments, but i already seen that it seems to be an error when installing postgresql via brew. It's not common, but it happens sometimes.

Here's a quick fix:

```
brew install libpqxx
```

Make sure to run also

`brew update`

and restart your PostgreSQL server via:

`brew services restart postgresql`

Also make sure to clean up brew:

`brew cleanup`

If the error is still there, post your Gemfile and your database.yml file as well.

Greetings!